# PUT method not working in django-tastypie?

Tags: python, django, curl, tastypie

I am new to django-tastypie. Here my api.py code,

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from .models import ListModel


class ListModelResource(ModelResource):

    def determine_format(self, request):
        return 'application/json'

    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get','put']
        queryset = ListModel.objects.all()
```

Here I am using CURL for GET:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/listmodel/1/

OUT: {"completed": false, "id": 1, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/listmodel/1/", "title": "This is test"}
```

Here I am using CURL for PUT:

```
 curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" '{"completed": false, "id": 1, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/listmodel/1/", "title": "This is test"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/listmodel/1/
HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Date: Wed, 04 Sep 2013 08:12:53 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2+
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Why I am getting 401 ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [tastypie tutorial](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html):

> ... if you try sending a POST/PUT/DELETE to the resource, you find
>   yourself getting “401 Unauthorized” errors. For safety, Tastypie ships
>   with the authorization class (“what are you allowed to do”) set to
>   ReadOnlyAuthorization. This makes it safe to expose on the web, but
>   prevents us from doing POST/PUT/DELETE. ..

You can enable it using `tastypie.authorization.Authorization`:

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from .models import ListModel

class ListModelResource(ModelResource):
    def determine_format(self, request):
        return 'application/json'

    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get','put']
        queryset = ListModel.objects.all()
        authorization= Authorization() # <---
```

> **Warning**
>
> This is now great for testing in development but **VERY INSECURE**.
>   You should never put a Resource like this out on the internet. Please
>   spend some time looking at the [authentication](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html)/[authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html) classes
>   available in Tastypie.